Decoupling Production processes from Logical Replication on AWS RDS PostgreSQL: Seeking Non-Blocking Alternatives for Tables Without Primary Keys
We recently encountered an issue in our production environment involving logical replication on our AWS RDS PostgreSQL 16.3 instances.
Our current setup allows developers to add tables to replication independently.
However, one of these tables doesn’t have a primary key or unique constraints by design, and when it was added without the proper REPLICA IDENTITY, we naturally received the following error:

ERROR: cannot update table 
"some_critical_prod_table" because it does not have a replica identity and publishes updates.

This error temporarily halted our production operations, until I was called in and set the replica identity to FULL to allow the system to continue it's work. (The table is quite small and not modified heavily, so I'm not concerned by the extra logging overhead)
I’ve been tasked with finding a replication solution that can replicate specific tables into a writable database—similar to the native PostgreSQL logical replication—while ensuring replication issues don’t directly impact production workloads. I initially considered AWS DMS, but since our tables contain enums, that option isn’t supported.
I’m open to exploring commercial tools or alternative approaches that can fully decouple production activities from the replication process, preventing replication-related problems from blocking DML operations.
Any recommendations or insights would be greatly appreciated.
(Yes, I fully agree that allowing anyone to freely add tables to the logical replication, or having tables with no PK\Unique are the main concerns to address here, but those are constraints I need to live with for time being)

You shouldn't have tables without primary key

If the developers can change the schema without your review, they have the responsibility to change it correctly. The developers need to add the REPLICA IDENTITY FULL to their change script. My business also allows developers to change the schema. I have given them rules and training. Including not doing some types of ALTER TABLES which will lock some large tables for 1 or more hours and halt production. If you have a tool that can scan their changes that would also help. Training.  Get your knowledge into their code review cycle.
